# c# dynamic template generation

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

my problem is this:

I read a xml configuration. In this configuration is a part of ui description like this.

```
<button1 menu="menu1" name="name1" ... /> 
<button2 menu="menu2" name="name2" ... /> 
<button3  ... />
```

Name is the visible Button Name. 
Menu is the Group in which the button is placed.

Now i want to build the ui based on this description. Or rather only the menu part. I read somethings about this and end on the keyword Datatemplate/Controltemplate. But i cant find a good solution so dynamic add my content at runtime to this templates.

My app based on mvvm light + ribbon lib. if you need any more information pls ask.

Summarized:
read xml config -> based on this build Datatemplate/Control or what else -> and add this to view

Here a picture for the illustration. Button2 has only no picture. 
[photo](http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/testaqzf16nspm.png)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how can i generate dynamicly the controls from the xlm description into the mvvm view + binding

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt would be to use the XML file as a data source and load that into a MenuViewModel class as a collection. Then build your menu using an items control, with an appropriate template.

The only part I'm unable to figure is what to do when a menu is selected, assuming you just need to know which is selected then that goes in the view model too as is bound to the items controls 'SelectedValue' property.

Comment: sry i forgot to say, the xml consists also some other things. Not only the ui description

Comment: Ok, do any of those things get in the way? You only need to pick out the bits you need.

Comment: Okay .. but is this real MVVM pattern? I create in a ModelView Class a View !?

Comment: It is. You don't create the view in the view model, you're just building the data to support 'a' view. You bind to it and build UI as you wish.

Comment: Ah okay ... but somethings miss for me to understand it.  Where i build the itemcontrol with the template ? (Iam new a mvvm so i need some more questions to understand ;))

Comment: That's in your view XAML file.

Comment: Hmmm ... but this fix. I want dynamic add controls.Like: 3 Buttons in the first menu ... 5 Buttons in the next menu  .. based on the description in the xml. But how can i do this with the itemcontrol and the template? I can say  2 Buttons in one Menu but not variable or ?

Comment: If you want a dynamic amount of menus, use a collection of collections and an items control with nested items controls. If you have a finite number of menus, create collections for each one and then create a items control for each in your view, using the same template.incidentally,not gave selected item binding use a listbox instead of items control.